# Install tracking needs to been exported or not?

Tags: android, security, manifest, android-lint

I am tracking my installs with two methods like you can see here in my manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name=".tracking.ReferralReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The second receiver generates a lint warning the first not. Does that mean that Google knows that for their `InstallReferrerReceiver` and know that it is safe to let it exported?

PS: I know I can use `tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent is broadcasted when an app is installed from the Google Play Store.
`android:exported="true"` means that the receiver is allowed to receive broadcast intents from other applications. You do want this, or you will not be able to receive the event which is sent by another app (the system or the Play Store app, I'm not sure).

However, if you check the documentation for `android:exported`, its default value is true if it has at least one `<intent-filter>`, otherwise it is false.

So to sum up, you need `android:exported="true"` to catch the event. But omitting this property would be also OK, since the default value is `true` for your receivers (but it's safer to have it).

About the Lint warning: It recognizes the name, and that's why it knows that the first version is safe.

Comment: So as I guessed, I can safely ignore this warning. I may open a bug since this is general for this action.

Comment: If you open a bug, open it as a feature request. It is only a warning, not an error.

Comment: IMHO it is an error that this warning appears. However this is not critical.